# Question about multiple values for the same key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I made a database with the following information, states, countys, zip codes, and the county website. It's sort of like this:

- 31233 Ohio Franklin site
- 31231 Ohio Franklin site
- 13231 Ohio Franklin site
- 12312 Ohio Delaware site
- 31231 Ohio Delaware site

I concanated the states and counties, so for OhioFranklin for example there would be 3 zip codes associated.

What I am trying to do is be able to pull up all of the zip codes for OhioFranklin, but everything I have tried to far only results in one of the zip codes being associated with the statecounty string.

The reason is that I have it set up in my program so you:

1. Enter a zip code
2. It outputs the county website
3. Ask for user input if they know a better website for the county
4. Then add that website to a new statecounty dict so every zip code for that statecounty will display the user suggestion

So for example:

- Enters 31233
- Pulls up OhioFranklin website
- User finds a better working website, enters the website into a field
- Add the website suggestion to the other zip codes associated with OhioFranklin 31231 and 13231

So now when they enter the zip code 31231 or 13231 it will display that user input as well.

It's the last step that I am struggling with, I'd appreciate any input.

```
with open('C:/Users/LTC/Work_stuff/concate.csv', mode='r') as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    statecounty = {}
    for row in reader:
        c = row[5]
        if c in statecounty.values():
            statecounty[c].append(row[0])
        else: statecounty[c] = row[0]
```

This is what I am trying right now but it still only adds one value

Update:

Got it working with

```
with open('C:/Users/LTC/Work_stuff/concate.csv', mode='r') as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    statecounty = {}
    for row in reader:
        c = row[5]
        b = row[0]
        statecounty[c] = [b] if c not in statecounty.keys() else statecounty[c] + [b]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no law that you are restricted to a single data structure! You need two dictionaries.

1. Mapping from zip code to name of location (as state+county)
2. Mapping from name of location to list of zip codes

So:

```
   zipMap = { "31233": "OhioFranklin", "31231": "OhioFranklin", "12345": "Elsewhere" ... }

   locMap = { "OhioFranklin": ["31233", "31231" ], "Elsewhere": ["12345"], ...}
```

Then you look up user input in zipMap, which gives you OhioFranklin.  Look up OhioFranklin in locMap, and it gives you all possible zip codes for that location.

If the user wants to add a better zip code, say 13231, you add that entry to zipMap, and then find the OhioFranklin entry in locMap, and extend the list by adding 13231.

---

A few example uses:

```
>>> zipMap = { "31233": "OhioFranklin", "31231": "OhioFranklin", "12345": "Elsewhere" }
>>> locMap = { "OhioFranklin": ["31233", "31231" ], "Elsewhere": ["12345"] }
>>> print(locMap)
{'OhioFranklin': ['31233', '31231'], 'Elsewhere': ['12345']}
>>> print(locMap["OhioFranklin"])
['31233', '31231']
>>> print(locMap[zipMap["31233"]])
['31233', '31231']
>>>
```

---

Input pseudo-code

```
   for each row: # assuming it's one state and zip per row
        read state and zip:
            add 'zip: state' entry to zipMap
            if state is already in locMap:
                extend the zip list to include the new zip
            else 
                else add 'state: [zip]' entry to locMap # note single-element list
```

(For 'state' I meant 'state and county'!)

Comment: I tried to accomplish that earlier,  but I keep running into the the same problem that I only get one value for each statecounty.

Comment: with open('C:/Users/LTC/Work_stuff/concate.csv', mode='r') as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    statecounty = {rows[5]:rows[0] for rows in reader}

Comment: Then when I print the dict each statecounty will have just one associated zip code

Comment: So don't "print the dict".  Write code that prints what you want.  The data are all available.  Actually, if you want a name-to-zips list, then printing locDict does what you want.  See example code added to answer.

Comment: I guess the real question is how do I actually add multiple values for each of the keys when I open the csv?

Comment: Oh, you mean your problem is on the input side?  In that case you need a more sophisticated input routine.  You can't just create `state: zip` if you expect the same `state` to appear on more than one row. You need to see whether you already have an entry for the state, and if so, append the zip.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't go exactly the route you suggested but it really helped me structure out the actual approach, thanks so much